# R: Using foreach with blotter, portfolio already exists error

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, quantstrat, blotter

I'm using the blotter package to run a backtest, and using foreach to speed things up. I'm running into an error where blotter finds the portfolio with the same name even though they are supposed to be removed at the start of the function. Here's a sample code to reproduce the error

```
require('foreach')
require('doSNOW')
require('xts')
require('blotter')

backtestFunction <- function() {

  currency("USD")
  stock("AAPL", currency="USD", multiplier=1)
  Sys.setenv(TZ="US/Eastern")
  verbose = FALSE

  try(rm("account.Snazzy","portfolio.Snazzy",pos=.blotter),silent=TRUE)
  initPortf("Snazzy", "AAPL", initDate="2014-01-01", currency="USD")
  initAcct("Snazzy", portfolios="Snazzy", initDate="2014-01-01", initEq=1000, currency="USD")

  return (TRUE)
}

cl <- snow::makeCluster(8, type = "SOCK")
registerDoSNOW(cl)

results <- foreach(i=1:100, .combine=rbind, .packages=c('xts','blotter')) %dopar% {
  return (backtestFunction())
}
snow::stopCluster(cl)
```

Here's the error

```
Error in { : 
  task 9 failed - "Portfolio Snazzy already exists, use updatePortf() or addPortfInstr() to update it."
```

I understand that the portfolio and account objects are stored in the .blotter environment, however

1. Wouldn't foreach spawn each worker in a new R session of sorts so that there will be no conflicts?
2. Why didn't the `try(rm("account.Snazzy","portfolio.Snazzy",pos=.blotter),silent=TRUE)` work?
3. How can I get foreach to work with blotter here?

If it matters, I'm using R 3.0.2, running RStudio on Windows. I'm including quantstrat in the tag because these are typically used together so its likely an experienced quantstrat user would know the fix. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that ".blotter" is being automatically exported to the workers, but to doSNOW's "export" environment, *not* to the global environment. This doesn't confuse the blotter package, but it does prevent your "rm" command from removing "account.Snazzy" and "portfolio.Snazzy" from the real ".blotter" environment.

One solution is to add `.noexport=".blotter"` to foreach. Another solution is to specify the environment more explicitly when executing "rm":

```
try(rm("account.Snazzy","portfolio.Snazzy",pos=.GlobalEnv$.blotter),
    silent=TRUE)
```

doSNOW doesn't spawn a worker for each task because that could be quite slow. Even for local workers, the time to launch an R session can be significant compared to the time to execute a task, especially on a cluster using ssh. And more importantly, if workers execute multiple tasks, you can send large data sets to them once, and reuse that data for many tasks, thus amortizing the communication costs.

Comment: Thanks Steve for the clarifications! I dug further and just to provide more details for others, the function's evaluation environment was enclosed by the temporary environment created by foreach/doSNOW, which in turn was enclosed by the global environment. So when ".blotter" was exported into the temporary environment, there was a ".blotter" in both the temporary environment and the global environment. The "rm" command latched on to the one in the temporary environment, while the blotter package used the one in the global environment.

Comment: That's quite right. That same technique is used by doMPI, doRedis, and when a cluster object is registered with doParallel. That temporary environment is what I call the "export" environment.